# Best practices for validating the configuration of a Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, validation, web-applications, configuration

I would like that my Spring-based web application were able to *validate* its configuration during startup.

This means for example:

- check if the **required folders** exist and are readable/writable
- check if the required **configuration keys** are set and consistent
- ...
- check any other **constraint** that is required for the correct functioning

How can you perform these checks and **notify** the system administrator if something is wrong?

The goal is to reduce the risk that some critical error arises when the application is actually going to need those resources that are bound to the wrong configuration.

**NOTE:** my approach is to use a special **EnvironmentValidation** bean that checks if the configuration/folder structure is ok and if not it throws an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want notifications you could set up an email notifier for example using log4j that would send any exceptions on startup to the system administrator.

if a configuration key is not present spring will not start up anyway.

check the keys are consistent with what?

checking folders exist and are readable/writable isn't something I'd really do in my webapp - this belongs in your deployment infrastructure. Saying that you could write your own custom checks as spring beans, load these first and throw an exception if some of your configuration fails validation.

Comment: with "the keys are consistent" I mean to make sure that they contain valid configuration (simple example, check if some integer is within given boundaries).

Comment: your objects themselves should be doing this type of boundary check. If you throw an IllegalArgumentException for example in the constructor of your spring bean this would validate during start up.

Comment: Ok, however my point is slightly different. I would like to make a "sanity check" at the startup, because the IllegalArgumentException might come at a late moment in the life of the application.
Let's say the application produces some data by interacting with some users. At some point the application needs to move this data from memory (session) to disk (for example as binary file) and it accesses the "faulty" parameters. At this point the application won't be able to recover and data or a portion of the business process will be at risk.

Comment: spring will instantiate each of your beans on container startup - you will get the IllegalArgumentException straight away if you do the check in the constructor.

Comment: ok, this is indeed one of the **best practices** I was trying to track down... :)
Actually performing all these checks in the constructor or in the "setConfiguration(Properties properties)" method should be enough. Thanks, it was a quite obvious thing but for some reason it didn't pop in my mind as a good solution :P

Answer (score 0):

During startup all errors will be logged in to server logs. Logs can be checked and system administrator can be notified.